# LaTeX: Choose paging start and end

Tags: latex

I'm writing a report in LaTeX and I want to start the paging after the summary when my introduction starts

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

% [...] some chapters

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\chapter{Introduction}
% here I want the paging to start with 1

% [...] some chapters

\chapter{Conclusion}
% here i want to end the paging

% [...] some chapters

\end{document}
```

So I'm asking if there's any solution to set where to start and end the paging or to ignore from paging some pages.

Also, I've already tried to add this line after the chapter "Introduction" :

```latex
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

But I can't choose where to end the counter and also all the pages before this one are counted and it's just restarting to 1 after the setcounter update.

### **EDIT**

I've found a way to solve it but I think it's not the most beautiful way. I've added `\thispagestyle{empty}` to every page where I don't want to see the paging and then added `\pagenumbering{arabic}` above my "Introduction" chapter to make the paging "restart" to this page.

Here's how it looks now :

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\begin{document}

% [...] some chapters
% \thispagestyle{empty} % added above every chapter I don't want to see paginated

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

% [...] some chapters

\chapter{Conclusion}

% [...] some chapters
% \thispagestyle{empty} % added above every chapter I don't want to see paginated

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use the `book` class instead of `report`. This way you can use `\mainmatter` to start the main part of your document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

% [...] some chapters

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
% here I want the paging to start with 1

% [...] some chapters

\chapter{Conclusion}
% here i want to end the paging

% [...] some chapters

\end{document}
```